# Конвертирование Enum в C#

Tags: c#, enum

Возможно глупый вопрос. Можно ли преобразовать один enum в другой? К пример

Namespace1.Enum1 a = Namespace1.Enum1.Value1. 
Namespace2.Enum1 b = (Namespace2.Enum1)a.
Если да, то при каких условия, распишите пожалуйста

Comment: Приведите оба Enum

Comment: предыдущий комментарий корректен, так как enum - это по сути число, просто если у них цифровые значения одинаковы, то достаточно явно привести один к другому, если разные, но есть определенная закономерность, то приводим к цифровую значению и прибавляем (убавляем, умножаем)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно. Предположим у вас два перечисления.

```
enum Enum1
{
    AA,
    BB,
    CC
}
enum Enum2
{
    AA,
    BB
}
```

Для преобразования вы сначала должны получить имя элемента первого перечисления и с помощью Enum.Parse() преобразовать во второй.

```
// Предположим это элемент первого Enum1
Enum1 first = Enum1.AA; 

// Получаем его имя в строковом формате
string firstName = first.ToString();

// try нужен в случае, если во втором перечислении отсутствует элемент из первого (например Enum1.CC)
try 
{
   // Преобразуем во второй Enum2
   Enum2 second = (Enum2)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enum2), firstName); 
}
catch { }
```

Или можно парсить с помощью TryParse.

```
if (Enum.TryParse(firstName, out Enum2 result))
{
    // Тут код в случае, если получилось преобразовать
    // Результатом является result
}
```

Comment: Ну для каких-то простых случаев это подойдёт, да. Но согласен с @Alexsandr Ter: может понадобиться формула для приведения одних интов к другим (умножения, вычитания). И может быть преобразование достаточно хитрое, что придётся писать таблицу преобразований. Но это плюс, да.